# Behaviour subject emits only the last value on route changes

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angular2-routing

post component subscribed to behaviour subject and gets a subscription of posts. First time is working good but when I go to another page and come back I only get the last value of the posts but I need all the list of posts like in the first time.

posts service:

```
  public getPosts(): BehaviorSubject<Post> {

  let postSubject: BehaviorSubject<Post> = new BehaviorSubject<Post>(Post.EMPTY_POST);

  this.db.list(this.getModelPath()).subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {

    posts.forEach((result) => {

      let post: Post = Post.fromObject(result);
      postSubject.next(post);

      // code ommited

      });

  return postSubject;

}
```

the Subscribed component : (post list component)

```
  public getPosts() {

this.showLoadingSpinner = true;

  this._postService.getPosts().subscribe((post: Post) => {

    if(Post.EMPTY_POST != post) {

      this.showLoadingSpinner = false;
      this.posts.push(post);
    } 
    this.hasPostError = false;

  }, (error) => {

      this.loggerService.error(error);
      this.showLoadingSpinner = false;
      this.loggerService.log("error occured while getting posts.")
      this.postErrorMessage = "error occured while getting posts.";
      this.hasPostError = true;

  }, () => {

      this.showLoadingSpinner = false;

      if (!this.posts.length) {

        this.postErrorMessage = "No posts to show!";
        this.hasPostError = true;

      }

  })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`BehaviorSubject` stores latest emitted value

Try to use [ReplaySubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#replaysubject)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be `next`-ing the entire array instead of just one element.

```js
 public getPosts(): BehaviorSubject<Post> {

  let postSubject: BehaviorSubject<Post> = new BehaviorSubject<Post>(Post.EMPTY_POST);

  this.db.list(this.getModelPath()).subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {

    this.postSubject.next(posts.map(post => Post.fromObject(post));

    return postSubject;  
}
```

Then you have to change the consuming code to use the last element in the emitted array when it emits, if you only want a single element.

This will give you the last snapshot of the list on load.